# Array de urls - Botão Próximo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**PHP**

```
$urls = Array('www.1.com.br','www.2.com.br', 'www.3.com.br');
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="www.1.com.br" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>

<button>Proximo</button>
```

Como faço para sempre que clicar no botão proximo atualizar só o iframe (não a pagina inteira) na sequencia de urls que estao no array php?

Estou em duvida também se é melhor um array com todas urls em javascript ou php

**UPDATE**

1 - As 3 respostas funcionaram para mim, mas as 3 tem um porém em comum: quando chega na ultima url do array, ao clicar novamente volta para a primeira url, deveria parar de ter ação ao clicar no botão Proximo quando finalizar as urls do array

2 - nos 3 exemplos a página inteira esta atualizando quando tem alteração na url do iframe

```
jQuery('#srcFrame').submit(function(){             
           $.ajax({
            url: 'updateUrl.php',
            type: '???',
            data: ????,
        });     
    })
```

Como faço pra usar o ajax pra só o iframe atualizar e como deve ser o arquivo updateUrl.php?

Comment: A resposta que você marcou como correta não faz isso que colocou no "*update*", não volta para o primeiro link.

Comment: mas não é para voltar para o primeiro link :) como esta escrito: `ao clicar novamente volta para a primeira url, deveria PARAR DE TER AÇÃO ao clicar no botão Proximo quando finalizar as urls do array`

Comment: E ela não volta, se estiver voltando é porque você usou o código do Ivan (que verifica o índice e, se for igual ao total de links, volta ao primeiro). :)

Comment: não, tanto o ivan como o Lucas fizeram alterações nas respostas durante o update. Se acompanhou, eu confundi e a do Lucas já estava correta,  antes mesmo de eu colocar o Update na minha questão

Comment: Mas aprendi muito com o Ivan tbm, ótimas explicações, mas o resultado final sem atualizar a pagina consegui entender com o Lucas. Novamente muito obrigada a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com Javascript, você pode alterar o `src` usando a função [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) ou [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) a cada evento click do botão, dessa forma:

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="frames" src="'www.google.com" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>
<button>Proximo</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var urls = ['www.google.com.br','https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html', 'www.globo.com.br'];
var frame = $("#frames");
var index = 0;

$("button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (index < urls.length)
        index++;
    $("#frames").attr("src", urls[index]);
});
```

**JsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/rmoqa2c7/

[event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) é uma função que serve para prevenir um comportamento padrão de determinado componente, portanto se você o user no submit, o comportamento padrão de atualizar a página não vai acontecer.

Comment: Obrigada pelas indicações das páginas no manual, seu código funcionou tem 2 coisas que ainda tenho duvida, atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: para parar de ter ação no botão, quando for:
`
 if ( index === urls.length) {
   click_button.disabled = true;
 }`

Comment: Realmente Lucas, o seu quando chega ao final do array não acontece mais nada ao clicar no botão

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` seria no inicio da function? aqui não mudou o comportamento

Comment: agora o botão não funciona na vai para a proxima url

Comment: como faço para que ao ter alteração no scr do iframe usar o preventDefault? Algo como onchange iframe src preventDefault

Comment: Seu codigo funcionou, não estava percebendo pois só tinha o iframe e o botão na pagina, coloquei outros conteudos dinamicos e consegui perceber que esta funcionando. O Chrome da a impressao de estar atualizando a pagina por causa do icone de atualização, testei no IE e de primeira deu pra perceber que só o iframe estava atualizando. Obrigada novamente pelas respostas :)

Answer (score 3):

Capture os elementos através da ID, e crie uma ação no botão, verificando qual o próximo índice que deverá ser clicado, a cada click, soma uma posição, se for igual ao total de url, ele reinicia para o índice 0 (início):

```
<button id="next">Proximo</button>

<iframe id="rotator" src="http://www.1.com.br" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
/* Para capturar o elemento por
   getElementById, independente da posição do script,
   é necessário que o documento window tenha sido lido */ 
    var urls = [
                'http://www.1.com.br',
                'http://www.2.com.br',
                'http://www.3.com.br'
        ];

    var index = 1;
    var click_button = document.getElementById('next');
    var el = document.getElementById('rotator');

    click_button.onclick = function() {
        if ( index === urls.length ) {
            index = 0;
        } 
        el.src = urls[index];
        index += 1;
    }
};
</script>
```

Se quiser implementar usando PHP diretamente no javascript, dá pra fazer assim, mas eu não recomendo, prefira enviar os dados via POST ou GET, mas daí ficaria para uma outra pergunta:

```
<?php $urls = array('http://www.1.com.br',
                    'http://www.2.com.br',
                    'http://www.3.com.br'); ?>
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    /* Para capturar o elemento por
       getElementById, independente da posição do script,
       é necessário que o documento window tenha sido lido */ 
        var urls = <?php echo '["'.implode('","', $urls).'"];'; ?>

        var index = 1;
        var click_button = document.getElementById('next');
        var el = document.getElementById('rotator');

        click_button.onclick = function() {
            if ( index === urls.length ) {
                index = 0;
            } 
            el.src = urls[index];
            index += 1;
        }
    };
</script>
```

> Resolução para os novos casos:

**Caso 1:**

```
   <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    /* Para capturar o elemento por
       getElementById, independente da posição do script,
       é necessário que o documento window tenha sido lido */ 
        var urls = [
                    'http://www.1.com.br',
                    'http://www.2.com.br',
                    'http://www.3.com.br'
            ];

        var index = 1;
        var click_button = document.getElementById('next');
        var el = document.getElementById('rotator');

        click_button.onclick = function() {
            if ( index === urls.length -1 ) {
               this.disabled = true;
            } 
            el.src = urls[index];
            index += 1;
        }
    };
    </script>
```

**Caso 2:**

Não ficou claro exatamente o problema. Pois ele carrega cada iframe na mesma página, se está atualizando, não tem a ver com o código que publiquei, mas com o resto do código que existe na sua aplicação, acredito eu.

Comment: Funcionou Ivan, os comentarios que colocou no código me ajudaram muito atualizei minha pergunta inserindo duas observações

Comment: Sobre o caso 2 é que quando clica no botão proximo o navegador inteiro tem um refresh, o refresh deveria ser só no iframe, atualizando só o iframe não a pagina inteira

Comment: o window.onload não é um reload. Ele apenas executa o código após a página ser carregada... você pode fazer o teste utilizando apenas páginas em branco, e verá que funciona normalmente.

Comment: sim, entendo, mas sabe aquele icone que usamos para atualizar a pagina no navegador (chrome por exemplo)? então, quando clicamos no botão proximo o icone do navegador roda, no caso de atualizar só o iframe ele não deve rodar, pq vai atualizar só o iframe não a pagina inteira

Comment: bom, você está fazendo uma ação em javascript, javascript não é server-side, se você clicar no botão atualizar, obviamente que ele irá perder tudo. para manter a posição, você teria que gravar a posição no banco via server-side, ou usar sessionStorage para manter um cache.

Comment: Por isso estou tentando entender como usar o Ajax

Comment: Você pode usar somente javascript para isso: `localStorage.setItem('posicao', index)` e captura com: `localStorage.getItem('posicao')`

Comment: A principal finalidade do ajax, é executar ações de maneira assíncrona.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="displayURL" src="www.1.com.br" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>

<button id="changeURL">Próximo</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var urls = "<?php echo implode('|', $urls) ?>".split('|');

$('#changeURL').click(function() {
    var i = urls.indexOf($('#displayURL').prop('src'));
    i = (i < 0) ? 0 : i+1;
    if(i <= urls.length-1) {
        $('#displayURL').prop('src', urls[i]);
    }
});
```

Ele transforma o array PHP em string separando os elementos por pipe, depois o javascript transforma essa string em array novamente, com esse array eu faço a lógica de troca no código abaixo, de acordo com o valor do src do iframe eu consigo achar o index no array e fazer ele ir pro próximo item, a menos que seja o último ou não exista, nesse caso eu seleciono o primeiro item do array.

OBS.: Eu to fazendo a separação da URL por pipe, mas você pode mudar pra qualquer caractere que não tenha nos seus links.

Comment: Obrigada Junior, gostei da ideia de implodir o array php dentro do javascript. Ainda tenho duas duvidas, atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: Atualizei o código pra primeira questão, a segunda você tem certeza que é a página toda que tá atualizando ou só o iframe?